# ASP Core .NET 6 works when I run it manually, but it fails when I install as windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, grpc

I have an ASP Core .NET 6 application that I want to install as windows services.

I am using minimal API and this is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Grpc;
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog.Events;



File.AppendAllText("LogManual.txt", DateTime.Now + ": Iniciado");


Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information("Starting up");





try
{
    WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions
    {
        Args = args,
        ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
    };
    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);


    builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
           .WriteTo.Console()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));


    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {
        string miStrCertificado = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.crt");
        string miStrKey = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.key");
        X509Certificate2 miCertficadoX509 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(miStrCertificado, miStrKey);
        X509Certificate2 miCertificado2 = new X509Certificate2(miCertficadoX509.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

        miCertficadoX509.Dispose();


        options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps(miCertificado2);
        });
    });



    builder.Services.AddGrpc();

    builder.Host.UseWindowsService();



    WebApplication app = builder.Build();


    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    app.MapGrpcService<GestorOrdenadoresService>();



    app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");



    await app.RunAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    File.AppendAllText("LogManual.txt", DateTime.Now + ": EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled exception");
}
finally
{
    File.AppendAllText("LogManual.txt", DateTime.Now + ": Finally");
    Log.Information("Shut down complete");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

When I debug or run the application manually, it creates the log, but when I install the service and try to run it, in the service manager of windows, when I click to start, I get the error 1067.

If I go to the event viewer of windows, I get the error with ID 7034.

And in this case no log files are created.

How the application can run when I run it manually, I guess the problem is how I try to set the service part of the code, but I don't know how could be the problem.

Comment: Do you debug with Release and corresponding architecture (anycpu/x86/x64)? Do you (manually) run the application with the same user account as your windows service does?

Comment: Well, the service is running by the system user and when I run manually I run as my own user (no admin user) and I debug as anyCPU, but I don't debug the release build, just I debug the debug build.

Comment: Can you try to bootstrap your logger in the try block? It is the only spot where the app would crash without logging anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it in this it doesn't help so much. In fact, the first line create a text file that it should give any problem. And this file is not create (line File.AppendAllText("LogManual.txt", DateTime.Now + ": Iniciado");). So the problem is that the services is not create correctly.

Comment: It could also crash in the catch blocks. If the file is write-protected or already opened by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Win32 services run in `%WinDir%\System32` by default](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/10/managed-windows-services-basics.html) (as I describe on my blog), and I'd be surprised if you could just write out a `LogManual.txt` in that folder. So, you're probably getting an exception, which is causing your service to fail to start.

A lot of services find this inconvenient, and change their working directory on startup:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: Thanks, putting this line as first line in the program.cs works perfecly. Thanks so much.